# Is there a way to size a border to its contents? (Winnrt Xaml)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a border around a textblock to create a nice background with rounded corners.  But no matter what I do the border width is always the size of its parent.  I want to limit it to the size of its contents.
I tried binding the width to the actual width of it's contents, but that didn't work, with any of the binding modes.

```
<Border x:Name="TagPreviewBorder" CornerRadius="5"
        Width="{Binding ElementName=TagPreviewTextBlock, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <TextBlock x:Name="TagPreviewTextBlock"/>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An easy workarround would be to forget `Border` in your xaml and 
use a `TextBox` instead of `TextBlock` like this:

```
<TextBox Text="Your Text Here" 
         IsReadOnly="True" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Red" 
         BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

**UPDATE:**
I checked again and seems that you have forgotten to set the `Border`'s HorizontalAlignment

This also works:

```
    <Border CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="10">
        <TextBlock Text="My Text Here"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
```

Comment: Ugh, I didn't realize that the horizontalAlignment was set to stretch by default.  Thank you very much for your help!